# Ojbc invoke js error: Can't find variable require

Tags: javascript, objective-c, web3js

I'm totally new to JS. I'm developing on ios and we need to use Web3js in our program. It's ok to call js function in obj-c. However, I use 'require' to import Web3js modules, it throws 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require'. What happens? Did I miss anything?
Anyone can help?? Many thanks.

update:

If 'require' is not usable, how could I use other modules from js invoked by obj-c?

here is my code.

obj-c code:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bridge/src/index" ofType:@"js"];
jsFunc = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

JSContext* jsContext = [[JSContext alloc] init];
[jsContext evaluateScript:jsFunc];
JSValue* func = jsContext[@"getAddress"];
JSValue* = [func2 callWithArguments:@[@"0x8730f6ad1c0d387644590966bdbfedba44fe250118df0f97f11190ad5727b312"]];
```

js:

```
function getAddress(prvKey)
{
  try{
      var Web3 = require('../../3rd_party/web3.js-1.0.0');     
      var web3 = new Web3();
      return web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(prvKey);
  }
  catch (e)
  {
      return e;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I'm going to take a guess that you are working with a straight javascript bridge within objective-c, but `require` is a standard function only in the Node.js runtime.  You might have to import the Web3js modules some other way.  But definitely need to see your code, and have you explain your setup to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have updated my code. I'm trying to develop a Ethereum library for our private chain. It includes, creating a raw transaction, encoding the ABIs and getting an address from a private key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Browserify to package all modules and then used webView to call the js functions.

here is my js file, index.js

```
"use strict"
let Web3 = require('web3.js');
window.Web3 = Web3;
```

and then use Broswerify to pack

```
browserify index.js -o web3.js
```

my html,

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="web3.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getAddress(prvkey)
        {
            try
            {
                var web3 = new Web3();
                var account  = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(prvkey);
                return account.address;
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                return e;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```